# Iterating in a JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON which looks like below.

```
[
{"Device":"Device1","Links"["NewLink","NewLink2","NewLink3"],"GeographicLocation":"NewLocation"},
{"Device":"Device2","Links":["NewLink"],"GeographicLocation":"NewLocation"}
{"Device":"Device3","Links":["NewLink","NewLink2"],"GeographicLocation":"NewLocation"}
]
```

I want to iterate through it and in the loop i want to alert the values of Links field.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried already?

Comment: this is not proper JSON

Answer (score 0):

If you have a json as a string you can use

```
var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

this will return an object array on which you can iterate.

See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [
   {"Device":"Device1","Links" ["NewLink","NewLink2","NewLink3"],"GeographicLocation":"NewLocation"},
   {"Device":"Device2","Links":["NewLink"],"GeographicLocation":"NewLocation"}
   {"Device":"Device3","Links":["NewLink","NewLink2"],"GeographicLocation":"NewLocation"}
];

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        var obj = arr[i];
        for(var key in obj){
            var attrName = key;
            var attrValue = obj[key];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = [
    {
        "Device": "Device1",
        "Links": [
            "NewLink",
            "NewLink2",
            "NewLink3"
        ],
        "GeographicLocation": "NewLocation"
    },
    {
        "Device": "Device2",
        "Links": [
            "NewLink"
        ],
        "GeographicLocation": "NewLocation"
    },
    {
        "Device": "Device3",
        "Links": [
            "NewLink",
            "NewLink2"
        ],
        "GeographicLocation": "NewLocation"
    }
];

for(var i=0; i<json.length ; i++)
{
    console.log(json[i].Device);
    console.log(json[i].Links);
    // for links use another loop
    for(var j=0; j<json[i].Links.length ; j++)
    {
        console.log(json[i].Links[j]);
    }
    console.log(json[i].GeographicLocation);
}
```

Comment: Yes it is jsonlint says valid

Answer (score 0):

Say you have your string `json`:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var links = data[i]['Links'];
    for(var j=0; j<links.length; j++) {
        //append this wherever
        document.write(links[j]);
        //if you're using jQuery, $('body').append(links[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[
{"Device":"Device1","Links":["NewLink","NewLink2","NewLink3"],"GeographicLocation":"NewLocation"},
{"Device":"Device2","Links":["NewLink"],"GeographicLocation":"NewLocation"},
{"Device":"Device3","Links":["NewLink","NewLink2"],"GeographicLocation":"NewLocation"}
]

var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

now it will work

you have missed **":"** and **" , "** in your JSON string

near the first **"Links":** and **},** add this